# CTRL + C в консольном приложении

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть код.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int error = 0;
    int num = 0;

    for (std::string day; std::cin >> day;)
    {
        if (day == "|") break;
        try
        {
            std::cin >> num;
            if (!std::cin)
            {
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(), EOF);
                std::cin.clear();
                throw std::exception("Enter the number\n");

            }
        }
        catch (std::exception)
        {
            std::cerr << "Input error\n";
            error += 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Почему при нажатии CTRL + C в 16 строке происходит выход из цикла, да и вообще выход из main. Хотя оператор if в 17 строке срабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что при нажатии <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> в консоли система останавливает запущенное приложение. Это действие по умолчанию, и может быть настроено (как - зависит от вашей ОС). Именно поэтому программа завершается.